# Is it correct to say "walk down the corridor and take the second left. The elevator is on the left"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

I am standing at 1 end of a corridor as shown in the above picture.

I want to go to the elevator 2.

Is it correct to say "**walk down the corridor and take the second right. The elevator is on the left**" or "**the elevator is just around the second corner on the left**"?

Comment: Grammatically, both are correct, but in fact it's the second *right*.

Comment: What is wrong with the first elevator just round the corner?

Comment: @WeatherVane, the 1st elevator is for block B & the 2nd one is for block C and we live in Block C.

Comment: "It's around the corner." It's obvious they are going to turn the closest corner. Don't make them walk too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is correct, but the first direction is not. The person you're instructing should take the second **right**!

Also, you could say "the elevator **will be** on your left"